# MySQL update updating all rows?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to create an sql query that will check through a table and if it cannot find a row in a different table with the same id then it modifies a field in the original table.

```
UPDATE book SET reserved = 'N' WHERE not exists ( SELECT * FROM reservedbooks WHERE book = $row[bookID]
```

I'm running this in a loop in php where $row[bookID] represents all the book ids. my problem is that when this finds a match it sets all of 'reserved' columns values to 'N', not just the one it cant find a value for.

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you need to add a WHERE clause to the update to specify the book id

Comment: ah okay is chaining WHERE's as easy as just adding another WHERE at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
UPDATE book SET reserved = 'N' WHERE id not in ( SELECT id FROM reservedbooks WHERE book = $row[bookID]
```

Comment: not really sure what id is suppose to represent there, is it a php variable assigned to the id num? just whacking that in there gives "Error: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'"

Comment: UPDATE book SET reserved = 'N' WHERE not exists ( SELECT * FROM reservedbooks WHERE book = $row[bookID] ) AND bookID = $row[bookID]

thanks for the help guys! :)